# Main method with different data type

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, minitab

Can I have Main with some different type argument like object type or anything else. Like in this case I want this

```
  static void Main(Mtb.Application app)
  {...}
```

But it is giving me error

> Error 1   Program 'C:\Users\abc\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\testmin\testmin\obj\x86\Debug\Abc.exe' does not contain
>   a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point    Abc

So, I want to ask, cant I use differnt type in main method other than string.

Thanks

Comment: If you could, how would it work? How would main be called? Where would the argument come from?

Comment: @jalf i am trying to pass minitab object to my application using Process class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, I want to ask, cant I use differnt type in main method other than string.

No, you can't. The arguments to the `Main` method are the ones passed on the command line, so it can only be an array of strings. How would you pass a `Mtb.Application` on the command line anyway?

Comment: ok fine sir. Is there any other way so that I can pass my mtb object in application. I am really struggling this for a week now.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed, well, where does this object come from? Another program?

Comment: yeah..actually i am creating minitab addin.and i want to pass minitab object to my application.I tried to add my form in addin but it gives me error. thats why i am now trying to call my application using Process class.

Comment: when i tried to add my form in addin it gives me error that you can see here. No one gives the answer to that question you can see error here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034337/active-analysis-throws-divide-by-zero-exception

Comment: @WaqarAhmed, you can't just pass an object to another process like that, it doesn't work that way. If it was an object representing data, you could serialize it and pass the file, but in this case it's the Minitab application, and it doesn't make sense to serialize it. Your plugin has to run in the same process as Minitab to be able to access the Application object.

Comment: To solve the problem in your other question, I suggest you contact the ActiveAnalysis support, as it seems the problem is in their product.

Comment: ok thanks for your detail information. I post the same problem on their forum as well. but they didnt replied yet, I hope they reply soon. But thanks for your answer and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Any of `Windows Application` or `Console Application` should have a `static void Main()` or `static void Main(string[] args)`, then your Main method is not a *Entrance Point* of .net application, this is just another overload of the original Main method.

if you want to pass a sth other than string to an application, you just save it to some where and pass the address of it to your app. then your answer is **NO**